# Multiple instances of jQuery Validation Plugin on a JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

SOLVED: $.extend() twice in a row simply overwrites the previous object because objects are passed by reference. My fix was to do this:

```
var updateUserObj = $.extend({}, validationPluginDefaults);
    var newUserObj = $.extend({}, validationPluginDefaults);
```

Then the validators are executed like this:

```
var whateverValidator = $.extend(updateUserObj,{new rules})
```

Update: Further research shows that what I'm trying to do appears to be correct but the problem may be in the object I am extending - "validationPluginDefaults"). Here it is below:

```
var validationPluginDefaults = {
ignore: [],
errorElement: 'p', //default input error message container <p>
errorClass: 'text-error', // default input error message class
focusInvalid: true, //focus on the first invalid field
messages: {},
invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit 

},
highlight: function (el) { // hightlight error inputs
    //jQuery(el).closest('.control-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
},
success: function (err, el) {
    jQuery(el).next(".text-error").hide();
    jQuery(el).next(".text-error").remove();


},
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
},
onfocusin: function () {},
onfocusout: function () {}
```

};

From my testing it appears that even though I have two separate forms on a JSP page and each has different validation that I can still only use one jQuery Validate Plugin instance per page; is this correct?

Here's my code:

```
// Define validation rules for form one
    var formOneValidator = $.extend(validationPluginDefaults,{
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                minlength: 2,
                onlyAlphaAndHyphen: true,
                required: true,
            },
            lastName: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true,
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });

    var formTwoValidator = $.extend(validationPluginDefaults,{
        rules: {
            newFirstName: {
                minlength: 2,
                onlyAlphaAndHyphen: true,
                required: true,
            },
            newLastName: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true,
            },
            newEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
            }
        }
    });

    $("#formOne").validate(formOneValidator); 
    $("#formTwo").validate(formTwoValidator);
```

What happens here is that formOne validator takes on all the rules of formTwoValidator after this code executes.

Is the solution to have only one validator and swap out rules depending on which form I'm in? It just seems strange that I wouldn't be able to define separate validators for each form on the page. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 0):

you could use knockout and give each page a different view model which handles the different validation. That is how i would do it but i'm sure there will be a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but using Knockout library isn't an option now. I'd like to get it working without it and I'm sure it must be possible.